# memory size exceeded?

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

i have a form that submits data to a database, i  have a function that looks like this:

```
//connect 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

now when i post, SOMETIMES i get an error that says this:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

i figured out that when i do a linebreak, or press enter in the message field, then that is when it causes the error, otherwise it works normal. any ideas?

Comment: Do you post any images at the same time? How large is the message your are trying to post? Are you sure the problem is withing the code you have posted? Seems abit strange as the code seems straight-forward. For testing, have you tried removing the mysql_real_escape_string() call, ex. with addslashes().

Comment: I think PHP will run the foreach on a copy of your POST-collection, however it would still be considered bad practice nevertheless, modifying the collection that you actually iterating over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to reproduce the error with

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(...

printf("<pre>Debug: count(_POST)==%d</pre>", count($_POST));
foreach ($_POST as $key => &$value) {
  printf("<pre>Debug: strlen(_POST[%s])==%d</pre>", htmlspecialchars($key), strlen($value)); flush();
  $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $mysql);
}
printf("<pre>Debug: Done.</pre>");
```

Does this print something "unusual" before the "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted" message?

edit and btw: I don't "like" the way you're trying to handle the real_escape_string thingy for two reasons:

- Leave _POST alone if possible, don't change its values. ( I'd make an exception for undoing magic_quotes though ;-) )
- Only process those fields you know you will need. Don't write an "encode and store in the database everything that is in _POST" function though it might sound like a good idea and super-reusable code. If you want to keep it somewhat reusable pass an array with descriptions to the function. In that array you can e.g. store information like [name of form field, allowed data type/validation rules, database field name]